# Wicket GUI elements loaded in runtime (OSGi?)

Tags: java, user-interface, osgi, wicket

I'm analyzing new approach for my application which should have GUI part automaticaly generated from XML description.

I have (generaly speaking source) with "description" of domain data. Something like

```
String with NAME
String wtih NICK
Boolean with MARIED
Integer with AGE
```

In my case it is data about somthing very complex so data above is here for abstraction. I have many of this XML and I have to be able in runtime of some WEB applicatin add another. (I'll add a XML file and application will be able to work with new "object" (generaly speaking create formular and view for this object).

My proposal was to generate (using something like XSLT) a OSGi bundle and that bundle in runtime use in program.

Please could you give some pros/cons for this approach (I'm a newbie in OSGi and not 100 sure it is possible or good aproach) or give me a hint how could be solved this issue? My only requirements are ability of loading new domain objects in runtime and using Wicket.

Thanks a lot for any advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need OSGi for this, you can use, for example, a `Panel` with a `Repeater` that adds appropriate UI elements, based on some configuration.